# F8 runs to other macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem. I have sub and function:

```
Sub test()
    For x = 1 To 12
        Range("a" & x) = x
    Next x
End Sub

Function funkcja(bok As Long) As Long
    funkcja = bok * bok
End Function
```

When I create new sub or change sub test and press f8 in sub after few steps f8 runs to function funkcja. I don't know why.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of your post. Also please consider reading the ["How to ask a good question" help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is `funkcja` used somewhere on the sheet?

Comment: If i create function but don't use on the sheet then it is ok , when i press f8 in sub don't runs to function , however if i use function on the sheet and create new sub or change existing sub then when i check sub by pressing f8 after few steps f8 runs to function . Next when i create new function and check sub by pressing f8 after few steps f8 runs to first and second fuction and so on .

Comment: Each time you change `Value` of a range, Excel recalculates all affected formulas. If you are in the debug mode when that happens, you get to step into functions called by Excel while recalculating.

Comment: So what I should or what I should not do ?

Comment: You should accept that this behaviour is normal. If it annoys you, then instead of pressing F8 every time, set breakpoints on relevant lines of code (F9) and use F5 to run from one breakpoint to another.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

1) Turn calculation to xlmanual at the start of the sub then back to xlautomatic at the end. This will stop it from running the function when the code updates the sheet.

2) Get rid of the function and where it appears in the sheet just make it whatever the value is ^2